# TYPO3: Problem with tx_news pagination and CoolUri

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I'm using tx_news and coolUri in my project. Everything works fine except the pagination. If i want to switch away from the first page nothing happens. The URL is changing but the view doesn't.

Did someone already have this problem and would have a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with tx_news and CoolUri and solved it by replacing the pagination wizard with the standard pagination wizard from TYPO3

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{news}" as="paginatedNews"configuration="{itemsPerPage: 10, insertAbove: 1, insertBelow: 1, maximumNumberOfLinks: 25}">
(...)
</f:widget.paginate>
```